# How to delete icons from comments in csv files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am try to delete an icons which appears in many rows of my csv file. When I create a dataframe object using pd.read_csv it shows a green squared check icon, but if I open the csv using Excel I see âœ… instead. I tried to delete using split function because the verification status is separated by | to the comment:

```
df['reviews'] = df['reviews'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')[1])
```

I noticed it didn't detect the "|" separator when the review contains the icon mentioned above.

[image]

I am not sure if it is an encoding problem. I tried to add encoding='utf-8' in pandas read_csv but It didn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

I would like to add, this is a pic when I open the csv file using Excel.

[image]

Comment: CSV files are text files. When you see such a checkbox or emoji in a text file you're seeing an actual character. The very fact you see it means the file is already UTF8. You can search, remove, replace or insert that character the same way you insert any other. `if I open the csv using Excel` how do you do that? Excel can't guess whether a file is UTF8 or not *unless* it starts with a Byte-Order-Mark. When you double-click on the file Excel will *import* it using the current user's locale settings, including the codepage. If you use the `Insert` menu instead, you can use UTF8

Comment: Can you please copy and paste that part of csv as text into the question ? Thanks

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Trim the `✅` character? Or load the file in Excel including it? Both are possible. I didn't copy an image here, I copied the ✅itself from [a table of Unicode characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2705). I didn't even use an escape sequence. If you want to remove such characters you can remove the characters themselves or use a regular expression to remove many of them at once, eg all symbols in the `Other Symbol` category or the `Dingbats` block

Comment: I would like to remove the green check (Unicode character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you had the following dataframe:

```
           reviews
0  ✅ Trip Verified
1     Not Verified
2     Not Verified
3  ✅ Trip Verified
```

You can use the replace method to replace the ✅ symbol which is **unicode character** `2705`.

```
df['reviews'] = df['reviews'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\u2705',''))
```

Here is the full example:

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"reviews":['\u2705 Trip Verified', 'Not Verified', 'Not Verified', '\u2705 Trip Verified']})
df['reviews'] = df['reviews'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\u2705',''))
print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
          reviews
0   Trip Verified
1    Not Verified
2    Not Verified
3   Trip Verified
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove non-latin characters using `encode/decode` methods:

```
>>> df
           reviews
0  ✓ Trip Verified
1         Verified

>>> df['reviews'].str.encode('latin1', errors='ignore').str.decode('latin1')
0     Trip Verified
1          Verified
Name: reviews, dtype: object
```

Comment: The question asks how to remove specific symbols, not non-Latin characters. Even for non-latin characters it's easier to actually remove those characters that go through a buggy encode/decode